# Interface is Task but I dont have any async code

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have been reading lots about Task lately, and I have to say I thought I understood it but once you read blogs by Stephen Cleary and Jon Skeet I have started to realize that there is more to it than one thinks.

So, I am implementing an interface that's based on TASK (this is not my interface its part of AspNet.Identity IUserPasswordStore ), Is this the correct way to implement this ?

```
public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => true);
}
```

This is kinda a trivial question, but you never know they might be an "ah, but did you know that this will do"

The rest of the code is all grown from async code so kinda just writes its self, well sort of , I need to convert begin/end pattern to TAP.

Comment: Please read the interface part, I will edit and add thats its not my interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't read well enough :)

In any case, when you just want to wrap a result in a finished task, there's no need to spin up new threadpool work. Just use

```
Task.FromResult(false)
```

For this case, it's okay to expose the `Task` in an interface. However, if you were to just use `Task.Run` or similar, don't. That's exactly the kind of things you'll find on Stephen's blog as "bad ideas". If your interface seems wide enough to accomodate things that are inherently asynchronous and at the same time inherently synchronous, you probably need to narrow your interfaces down.

Comment: thanks, i should have really looked a little harder :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am implementing an interface that's based on TASK , Is this the
>   correct way to implement this ?

Generally speaking, no. [You shouldn't expose async wrappers over sync methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Why shouldn't you do so? because it may confuse the end user which believes your method is purely an async IO bound operation (as that is what most of the BCL exposes for us), but will be surprised to see that it actually isn't.

That is why the recommended approach is to *let the user explicitly invoke the synchronous version on a new thread*.

Instead, do this:

```
public bool HasPassword(ApplicationUser user)
{
    return true;
}
```

And let *him* delegate it:

```
var hasPassword = Task.Run(() => HasPassword(user));
```